Istio configuration for persistent connections for push notifications using SSE with Spring WebFlux
I am new to Istio and need help configuring it to maintain persistent connections for push notifications using Server-Sent Events (SSE) with Spring WebFlux. My goal is to ensure these connections remain reliable and active 24/7(connection should be keep alive)
I have set istio configuration for others microservice it's working fine but here my connection should be persistence
Where I need to set rules for persistence connections.? (In istio)
Please do reply..

Spring WebFlux Application: Handles SSE for push notifications.
Kubernetes Deployment and Service: Deployed the Spring WebFlux application.
Istio: Installed and configured in the Kubernetes cluster(EKS).

I have enabled Istio sidecar injection.
And Created virtual service and Gateway and DestinationRule
How to configure this using istio..?
Any guidance or examples from similar implementations would be greatly appreciated!

Please use idleTimeout value for http connections in destination rule.  More details of connection pool settings are in istio documentation.
Below is sample of destination rule for idle timeout
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: bookinfo-redis
spec:
  host: myredissrv.prod.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    connectionPool:
      http:
        idleTimeout: "86400s"

